# Does my facebook messenger bot have to be approved and public to see the persistent menu?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger-bot

I set my Persistent Menu and got a success message in Terminal, but I still can't see the menu.

on the facebook messenger API page it says this:

> The page the bot is attached to must be published.
>
> The bot must be set to "public" in the developer console.
>
> The bot must have passed the approval process for pages_messaging permissions.

Is this true? I cant test it just as a developer?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't have to be approved, just public via the Facebook Developers console. Also, where do you host it? If on Heroku (free tier), your instance may need to "wake" before the persistent menu is pushed to you.